¿Cuándo y cómo adquirió "pedo" la acepción de "borrachera"?
La definición clásica de PEDO es:

m. Ventosidad que se expele del vientre por el ano.

y así aparece recogida como única acepción en el Diccionario de la Lengua hasta, al menos, 1992.
En la actualidad, sin embargo, aparecen otras acepciones adicionales:


borrachera (‖ efecto de emborracharse).
fiesta (‖ reunión para divertirse).
Ebrio, bajo los efectos del alcohol o de otra droga.


¿Cómo surgieron esas acepciones y se relacionan precisamente con pedo?
En la pregunta relacionada ¿Por qué un "pedal" es una borrachera? se hace referencia a esas acepciones de "pedo", pero no a su origen

Dónde están los moderadores cuando se los necesita?

RAE: m. El Salv. y Méx. fiesta (‖ reunión para divertirse).
Sin.: fiesta, chonguenga, party, fiestoca.

Cuando se trata de lenguaje coloquial, se está hablando del lenguaje hablado, por lo que no se puede establecer una fecha exacta de la primera aparición de esas palabras, solo se puede decir que esas palabras se remontan al siglo XX.
Esta evolución en el significado se debe a la tendencia del lenguaje coloquial de utilizar términos humorísticos o eufemísticos para referirse a situaciones sociales, como el estado de embriaguez.
La relación entre "pedo", "borrachera" y “ebrio” puede estar vinculada a la idea de que una persona ebria puede comportarse de manera desinhibida o ridícula, similar a la forma en que se percibe el acto de expulsar una ventosidad.
La relación entre "pedo" y "fiesta" puede estar vinculada a la idea de que una fiesta suele ser un evento ruidoso y desinhibido, similar a la percepción humorística de una ventosidad.

ChatGPT answer .-
